# android studio Score,CurrentHighScore and Total HighScore

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sharedpreferences

I'm developing a game and I have intermediate level of code knowledge. There are 10 levels in total in my game. I record the score instantly and compare it with the high score of the level, which is more.

I want to keep the high score data in each level and collect it with all levels and print a TextView.

You will see in the code that I tried with Sharedpreferences. Result: Each level writes its own high score to the TextView. I want the sum of the high scores of all the levels to be written to the TextView.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView scoreText,failedText,successText,highScoreText,randomArray;
    int score;
    public static int highScore,totalScore,totalScore2;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        score = 0;

        //totalScore = highScore + totalScore2;
        //totalScore2 = key.getInt("high_score_level2",0);

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Genel Skor : "+ totalScore , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "High : "+ highScore , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        levelFailed = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.levelFailed);
        levelSuccess = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.levelSuccess);
        highScoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHighScore);
        startTimer();
}

        private void startTimer(){
        start = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTime);
                timeText.setText("Zaman : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTime);
                timeText.setText("Süre Doldu ! ");
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

                for (ImageView image : imageArray) {
                    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                int x = 0;
                if (score < 10){
                    showFailedAlertDialog(R.layout.my_failed_dialog);

                }
                else if (score >= 10){
                    showAlertDialog(R.layout.my_success_dialog);
                    highScore();
                }


            }
        }.start();
    }


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void highScore(){
        SharedPreferences myScore = getSharedPreferences("my_pref",MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (highScore > score) {
            highScoreText.setText("Highscore: " + highScore);

        } else {
            highScore = score;
            highScoreText.setText("Highscore: " + highScore);
            myScore.edit().putInt("high_score_level1", highScore).apply();

            user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            //Upload user data
            if (isOnline() && user != null && user.getDisplayName() != null) {
                final DatabaseReference refDirect = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                refDirect.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        refDirect.child("Users" + "/" + user.getUid() +   
                        "/name").setValue(user.getDisplayName());
                        refDirect.child("Users" + "/" + user.getUid() + 
                        "/image").setValue(user.getPhotoUrl().toString());
                        refDirect.child("Users" + "/" + user.getUid() + "/highscore").setValue(highScore);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    }



        public void showAlertDialog(int my_success_dialog){
        builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View layoutView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_success_dialog,null);

        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(Main2Activity.this);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
        }

        randomArray = (TextView) layoutView .findViewById(R.id.successMessage);
        randomArray.setText("");

        successText = (TextView) layoutView .findViewById(R.id.txtSuccessScore);
        successText.setText("Skor: " + score);

        highScoreText = (TextView) layoutView .findViewById(R.id.txtHighScore);
        highScoreText.setText("Highscore: " + highScore);

        int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(levelSuccess.length);
        String randomName = levelSuccess[randomIndex];
        randomArray.setText(randomName);

        AppCompatButton dialogButton = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.successAnaMenu);
        AppCompatButton dialogButtonTwo = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.successNextLevel);
        builderDialog.setView(layoutView);
        builderDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog = builderDialog.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                Main2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        dialogButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main5Activity.class);
                Main2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
SharedPreferences myScore = getSharedPreferences("my_pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        totalScore = myScore.getInt("high_score_level2",0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Highscore level2 : "+ totalScore , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (highScore > score) {
            highScoreText.setText("Highscore: " + highScore + totalScore);

        } else {
            highScore = score;
            highScoreText.setText("Highscore: " + highScore + totalscore);
            myScore.edit().putInt("high_score_level1", highScore).apply();
```

[image]

1-Sharedpreferences pass to value next activity
2-Firebase database get value but i failed

Comment: What's the question for us? Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I want to have the sum of the high scores of all the levels in the High Score TextView. Example : Level 1 + Level 2 : 30 to TextView

Comment: In that case, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: My problem is not related to Firebase Database. I have explained the problem in great detail. @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

Since the data structure hasn't been detailed or retrieved, I've provided a random example assuming any key name. Please replace it as per your requirements.

Whenever a score is updated, you'll need to calculate the highscore using a for loop. Additionally, I'm storing the highscore for alternative usage

```
final DatabaseReference refDirect = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
refDirect.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String uid = user.getUid();
        refDirect.child("Users").child(uid).child("name").setValue(user.getDisplayName());
        refDirect.child("Users").child(uid).child("image").setValue(user.getPhotoUrl().toString());

        // Assuming you have a list of levels and their respective high scores
        List<LevelScore> levelScores = calculateHighScoresForLevels(dataSnapshot);

        int totalHighScore = 0;

        for (LevelScore levelScore : levelScores) {
            refDirect.child("Users").child(uid).child("highscores")
                .child(levelScore.getLevelId()).setValue(levelScore.getScore());

            totalHighScore += levelScore.getScore(); // Calculate total high score
        }

        refDirect.child("Users").child(uid).child("totalHighScore").setValue(totalHighScore);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Handle onCancelled if needed
    }
});
```